# How to fit big tables in one sheet?

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I have this very large table which I cannot fit in one single sheet.
The idea would be or to use landscape (but still it goes into another sheet) or to put it vertically (best solution).

Would you know how to do it?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{longtable}[l]{lccccccccc}
        \caption{VAR Estimation Results}
        \label{my-label}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Dependent Variables}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$rtb_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$xIG_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ $xHY_t$}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$xEM_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$xConv_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$y_t$}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$DefRate_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$spr_t$}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$R^2$}}\\
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \endhead
        %
        \toprule
        ~~$rtb_{t+1}$ & 0.9038  & 0.0872  & -0.0239  & -0.0279 &   0.0004 &  -0.2039  & -0.0172  &   0.1384 &\\
         & (2.1620)  &  (2.5739) & (-0.7706)  & (-0.9658)  &  (0.0330)  & (-1.1606)  & (-1.1140) &  (3.2121) &\\
        ~~$xIG_{t+1}$ & 0.1275  &  0.3683  & -0.0481  & -0.2046  &  0.0453  &  0.8365  &  0.0629  &  0.1911&\\
        & (0.7783) &  (2.2406)  & (-0.5394)  & (-1.9506)  &  (1.0510)  &  (1.4690)  &  (1.5138)  &  (1.0819) &\\
        ~~$xHY_{t+1}$  & 0.3392  & 0.4406  & -0.0890  &  0.1170  &  0.1419 &  -0.1556 &  -0.0070   & 0.3028& \\
        & (1.3632)  &  (1.3334)  & (-0.6600)  &  (0.6035)  &  (1.6819) &  (-0.1464) & (-0.0900)  &  (0.9893)& \\
        ~~$xEM_{t+1}$  & 0.4025  &  0.7190 &  -0.0523  & -0.3276  &  0.1349  & 1.9086 &  0.0128 &   0.2404&\\
        & (1.5669)  &  (1.9427)  & (-0.6229)  & (-1.6961) &   (1.7558)  &  (1.7899)   & (0.2595)   & (0.9980) &\\
        ~~$xConv_{t+1}$  & 0.7229 &  0.3615  & -0.0278  &  0.0637  &  0.1026  &  0.6163 &  -0.0360 &  -0.0710& \\
        & (2.3238)   &  (1.0195) & (-0.1533)  &  (0.2868)  &  (0.8016) &   (0.3322)  & (-0.3836)  & (-0.2200)& \\
        ~~$y_{t+1}$ & -0.0087  & -0.0215 &   0.0006  &  0.0140  & -0.0049  &  0.8962  &  0.0018 &  -0.0089 &\\
        & (-1.0722) &  (-1.9254)  &  (0.2111)  &  (2.3309)  & (-2.0655)  & (9.1198)  &  (0.8533) &  (-1.1866)&\\
        ~~$DefRate_{t+1}$ & 0.0662 &  -0.0655  &-0.0094 &   0.0486 &  -0.0153   & 0.5947  &  0.9504  &  0.2086& \\ 
        & (2.7102)  & (-2.1225) & (-0.6587)  &  (2.4579)  & (-1.7263)  &  (4.7462) &  (8.2119)  &  (6.4868)& \\ 
        ~~$spr_{t+1}$ & -0.0196  &  0.0289  & -0.0636 &  -0.0349  & -0.0061  &  0.0552  & -0.0073  &  1.0028&\\     
        & (-2.0809)   &  (1.5845)  &  (-7.7777)   & (-2.0494) &  (-1.1787)  &  (0.9975) &  (-1.2758)  & (5.4443)& \\ 
        \toprule  
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cross-Correlation Of Residuals} \\ 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$rtb_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$xIG_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ $xHY_t$}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ $xEM_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$(xConv_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$y_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$DefRate_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$spr_t$}}   \\
        ~~$rtb_{t+1}$ & - & 0.1140 &  0.0502 &  0.0207  &   0.1135  &   0.2269  &   0.1019  &   0.0339 \\
        ~~$xIG_{t+1}$ & - & - & 0.5636  &   0.7684  &   0.3342  &  -0.0310 &   -0.0992  &  -0.0556  \\
        ~~$xHY_{t+1}$  & - & - & - & 0.7265  &   0.7244  &  -0.0856  &  -0.1109   &  0.1040 \\
        ~~$xEM_{t+1}$ & - & - & - & - &   0.5508  &  -0.2182  &  -0.1723  &  -0.0318 \\
        ~~$xConv_{t+1}$ & - & - & - & - & - & 0.0071 &   -0.0735 &   -0.0327\\
        ~~$y_{t+1}$ & - & - & - & - & - & - & 0.1840  &  0.0032 \\ 
        ~~$DefRate_{t+1}$ & - & - & - & - & - &  - & - &-0.0796 \\ 
        ~~$spr_{t+1}$ & - & - & - & - & - & -  & - & - \\ 
        \bottomrule             

    \end{longtable}

    \end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The last column seem to be unused.

Comment: @Bernard Hi, I simply forgot to add the values for the R squared!

Comment: OK. It can fit in portrait orientation slightly redesigning the layout, and reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` and the font size.

Comment: Just one question: `rtb`, `xConv`, `xIG` , &c., are function names?

Comment: @Bernard I would not like to reduce the font size ...it has to fit on a paper and it would not look great if the font size is different. Those are simply descriptions of variables I am testing.

Comment: It should fit  with the `\small` size. In my opinion, down to `\footnotesize`, it's not a major problem,and it remains readable. Other solution, as you suggested: `landscape` orientation. I suppose you want 4 decimal digits, not 3?

Comment: @Bernard I could go for the 3 digits ...it would be a better option than reducing and then going for landscape. Do you think it would work in this case?

Comment: If we reduce to `\small`, we don't have to go for landscape either.  It's fairly common to (slightly) reduce the font size for tables.

Comment: @Bernard I just tried with landscape but it also goes in two sheets, could you provide code for your landscape solution?

Comment: Yes, in a moment. I have to put the finishing touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this layout in portrait orientation, with `S` columns for  the alignment of numbers on the decimal dot. Actually, in the present state, you don't need  `longtable` really.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rtb}{rtb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spr}{spr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IG}{IG}
\DeclareMathOperator{\HY}{HY}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EM}{EM}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Conv}{Conv}
\DeclareMathOperator{\DefRate}{DefRate}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.4, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre={(}, table-align-text-pre=false, table-space-text-post={)}}
\small
    \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}l@{}*9{S}}
        \caption{VAR Estimation Results}
        \label{my-label}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{10}{l}{\bfseries Dependent Variables}\\
        & {\thead{$\rtb_t$}} & {\thead{$x\IG_t$}} & {\thead{$x\HY_t$}} & {\thead{$x\EM_t$}} &{\thead{$x\Conv_t$}} & {\thead{$y_t$}} & {\thead{$\DefRate_t$}} & {\thead{$\spr_t$}}&{\thead{$R^2$}}\\
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \endhead
        %
        \toprule
        ~~$\rtb_{t+1}$ & 0.9038 & 0.0872 & -0.0239 & -0.0279 & 0.0004 & -0.2039 & -0.0172 & 0.1384 &\\
  & {(}2.1620{)} & {(}2.5739{)} & {(}-0.7706{)} & {(}-0.9658{)} & {(}0.0330{)} & {(}-1.1606{)} & {(}-1.1140{)} & {(}3.2121{)} & \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$x\IG_{t+1}$ & 0.1275 & 0.3683 & -0.0481 & -0.2046 & 0.0453 & 0.8365 & 0.0629 & 0.1911&\\
    & {(}0.7783{)} & {(}2.2406{)} & {(}-0.5394{)} & {(}-1.9506{)} & {(}1.0510{)} & {(}1.4690{)} & {(}1.5138{)} & {(}1.0819{)} & \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$x\HY_{t+1}$ & 0.3392 & 0.4406 & -0.0890 & 0.1170 & 0.1419 & -0.1556 & -0.0070 & 0.3028& \\
    & {(}1.3632{)} & {(}1.3334{)} & {(}-0.6600{)} & {(}0.6035{)} & {(}1.6819{)} & {(}-0.1464{)} & {(}-0.0900{)} & {(}0.9893{)}& \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$x\EM_{t+1}$ & 0.4025 & 0.7190 & -0.0523 & -0.3276 & 0.1349 & 1.9086 & 0.0128 & 0.2404&\\
   & {(}1.5669{)} & {(}1.9427{)} & {(}-0.6229{)} & {(}-1.6961{)} & {(}1.7558{)} & {(}1.7899{)} & {(}0.2595{)} & {(}0.9980{)} & \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$x\Conv_{t+1}$ & 0.7229 & 0.3615 & -0.0278 & 0.0637 & 0.1026 & 0.6163 & -0.0360 & -0.0710& \\
   & {(}2.3238{)} & {(}1.0195{)} & {(}-0.1533{)} & {(}0.2868{)} & {(}0.8016{)} & {(}0.3322{)} & {(}-0.3836{)} & {(}-0.2200{)}& \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$y_{t+1}$ & -0.0087 & -0.0215 & 0.0006 & 0.0140 & -0.0049 & 0.8962 & 0.0018 & -0.0089 &\\
  & {(}-1.0722{)} & {(}-1.9254{)} & {(}0.2111{)} & {(}2.3309{)} & {(}-2.0655{)} & {(}9.1198{)} & {(}0.8533{)} & {(}-1.1866{)}& \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$\DefRate_{t+1}$ & 0.0662 & -0.0655 &-0.0094 & 0.0486 & -0.0153 & 0.5947 & 0.9504 & 0.2086& \\
   & {(}2.7102{)} & {(}-2.1225{)} & {(}-0.6587{)} & {(}2.4579{)} & {(}-1.7263{)} & {(}4.7462{)} & {(}8.2119{)} & {(}6.4868{)}& \\
\addlinespace
        ~~$\spr_{t+1}$ & -0.0196 & 0.0289 & -0.0636 & -0.0349 & -0.0061 & 0.0552 & -0.0073 & 1.0028&\\
  & {(}-2.0809{)} & {(}1.5845{)} & {(}-7.7777{)} & {(}-2.0494{)} & {(}-1.1787{)} & {(}0.9975{)} & {(}-1.2758{)} & {(}5.4443{)}& \\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 \multicolumn{10}{l}{\bfseries Cross-Correlation of Residuals} \\
& {\thead{$\rtb_t$}} &{\thead{$x\IG_t$}} & {\thead{$x\HY_t$}} & {\thead{$x\EM_t$}} &{\thead{$x\Conv_t$}} & {\thead{$y_t$}} & {\thead{$\DefRate_t$}} & {\thead{$\spr_t$}} \\
 ~~$\rtb_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & 0.1140 & 0.0502 & 0.0207 & 0.1135 & 0.2269 & 0.1019 & 0.0339 \\
 ~~$x\IG_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & 0.5636 & 0.7684 & 0.3342 & -0.0310 & -0.0992 & -0.0556 \\
 ~~$x\HY_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 0.7265 & 0.7244 & -0.0856 & -0.1109 & 0.1040 \\
 ~~$x\EM_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 0.5508 & -0.2182 & -0.1723 & -0.0318 \\
 ~~$x\Conv_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 0.0071 & -0.0735 & -0.0327\\
 ~~$y_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 0.1840 & 0.0032 \\
 ~~$\DefRate_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} &-0.0796 \\
 ~~$\spr_{t+1}$ & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the version in landscape, formal font size  and the default `\tabcolsep`:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! This definitely helps. Would be possible to also see the one with landscape without \small?

Comment: @madrac: I've added a screenshot of the landscape version.

Answer (score 0):

An answer similar to [@Bernard's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438833/5001), but without resorting to **bold-facing**. (There's no need for this visual equivalent of **shouting** at your readers.) And, since page-breaking is neither desirable nor necessary, I've replaced `longtable` with `table` and `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}  % load if necessary
\usepackage[skip=0.3333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,pdflscape,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % "variable name"

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\caption{VAR Estimation Results}
\label{my-label}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{d{2.5}} c @{}}
\toprule
Dependent Variables & 
\mc{$\vn{rtb}_t$}   & \mc{$\vn{xIG}_t$}& \mc{$\vn{xHY}_t$} & \mc{$\vn{xEM}_t$} & 
\mc{$\vn{xConv}_t$} & \mc{$y_t$}   & \mc{$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & \mc{$\vn{spr}_t$} & $R^2$ \\
\midrule
$\vn{rtb}_{t+1}$ & 0.9038  & 0.0872  & -0.0239  & -0.0279 &   0.0004 &  -0.2039  & -0.0172  &   0.1384 &\\
 & (2.1620)  &  (2.5739) & (-0.7706)  & (-0.9658)  &  (0.0330)  & (-1.1606)  & (-1.1140) &  (3.2121) &\\
$\vn{xIG}_{t+1}$ & 0.1275  &  0.3683  & -0.0481  & -0.2046  &  0.0453  &  0.8365  &  0.0629  &  0.1911&\\
& (0.7783) &  (2.2406)  & (-0.5394)  & (-1.9506)  &  (1.0510)  &  (1.4690)  &  (1.5138)  &  (1.0819) &\\
$\vn{xHY}_{t+1}$  & 0.3392  & 0.4406  & -0.0890  &  0.1170  &  0.1419 &  -0.1556 &  -0.0070   & 0.3028& \\
& (1.3632)  &  (1.3334)  & (-0.6600)  &  (0.6035)  &  (1.6819) &  (-0.1464) & (-0.0900)  &  (0.9893)& \\
$\vn{xEM}_{t+1}$  & 0.4025  &  0.7190 &  -0.0523  & -0.3276  &  0.1349  & 1.9086 &  0.0128 &   0.2404&\\
& (1.5669)  &  (1.9427)  & (-0.6229)  & (-1.6961) &   (1.7558)  &  (1.7899)   & (0.2595)   & (0.9980) &\\
$\vn{xConv}_{t+1}$  & 0.7229 &  0.3615  & -0.0278  &  0.0637  &  0.1026  &  0.6163 &  -0.0360 &  -0.0710& \\
& (2.3238)   &  (1.0195) & (-0.1533)  &  (0.2868)  &  (0.8016) &   (0.3322)  & (-0.3836)  & (-0.2200)& \\
$y_{t+1}$ & -0.0087  & -0.0215 &   0.0006  &  0.0140  & -0.0049  &  0.8962  &  0.0018 &  -0.0089 &\\
& (-1.0722) &  (-1.9254)  &  (0.2111)  &  (2.3309)  & (-2.0655)  & (9.1198)  &  (0.8533) &  (-1.1866)&\\
$\vn{DefRate}_{t+1}$ & 0.0662 &  -0.0655  &-0.0094 &   0.0486 &  -0.0153   & 0.5947  &  0.9504  &  0.2086& \\ 
& (2.7102)  & (-2.1225) & (-0.6587)  &  (2.4579)  & (-1.7263)  &  (4.7462) &  (8.2119)  &  (6.4868)& \\ 
$\vn{spr}_{t+1}$ & -0.0196  &  0.0289  & -0.0636 &  -0.0349  & -0.0061  &  0.0552  & -0.0073  &  1.0028&\\ 
& (-2.0809)   &  (1.5845)  &  (-7.7777)   & (-2.0494) &  (-1.1787)  &  (0.9975) &  (-1.2758)  & (5.4443)& \\ 
\addlinespace
\midrule  
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Cross-Correlations of Residuals} \\ 
& \mc{$\vn{rtb}_t$}   & \mc{$\vn{xIG}_t$} & \mc{$\vn{xHY}_t$}     & \mc{$\vn{xEM}_t$} 
& \mc{$\vn{xConv}_t$} & \mc{$y_t$}        & \mc{$\vn{DefRate}_t$} & \mc{$\vn{spr}_t$} &   \\
$\vn{rtb}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& 0.1140 &  0.0502 &  0.0207  &   0.1135  &   0.2269  &   0.1019  &   0.0339 \\
$\vn{xIG}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& 0.5636  &   0.7684  &   0.3342  &  -0.0310 &   -0.0992  &  -0.0556  \\
$\vn{xHY}_{t+1}$  & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& 0.7265  &   0.7244  &  -0.0856  &  -0.1109   &  0.1040 \\
$\vn{xEM}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}&   0.5508  &  -0.2182  &  -0.1723  &  -0.0318 \\
$\vn{xConv}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& 0.0071 &   -0.0735 &   -0.0327\\
$y_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& 0.1840  &  0.0032 \\ 
$\vn{DefRate}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}&  \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}&-0.0796 \\ 
$\vn{spr}_{t+1}$ & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}} & \mc{\text{--}}& \mc{\text{--}}\\ 
\bottomrule 

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```